# .deb package postinst call another script in package

Tags: bash, debian, packaging, deb

Is it possible to call another bash script within postinst?

I am trying to call another bashscript which is inside of the debian package. Currently I do not seem to be having any luck doing this.

```
<postinst>
./postinst_script_2
```

Comment: The path name looks horribly wrong. Where does the package install the script on the target system? Use an absolute path; you have no way to guess or predict in which directory the user is going to be running `apt-get` (or `dpkg`, or some wrapper for either of these).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can call another bash script from inside your package during postinst. The postinst happens after the package is unpacked into the filesystem.

You probably can't depend on what the current directory will be when the postinst is run, though. tripleee is right; use an absolute path to call it.